# Perfmon returns unusual performance objects

Tags: perfmon

I have a several servers in a cluster. One of them is misbehaving and running slowly. I connect to it remotely with PerfMon:

Using the "Add Counters" dialog I select my remote server and in the "Performance object" drop down I see a list of numbers - they look like PIDs. If I connect to any of the other servers in the cluster I see the usual list of performance objects such as processor, server etc.

So why would PerfMon only be seeing ID's on "bad" server and not names? What could be wrong with this server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run through the procedure referenced in the article below to rebuild the performance counters on the problem machine. I haven't seen exactly the symptom you're reporting, but I have found that this procedure helps with general performance counter strangeness in most cases.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried rebooting the server? I hate suggesting a reboot as it seems such a cop out, but it would be worth a try.

JR

Comment: Yes - server reboot was the first thing I did but it did not make any difference. I agree that it seems like a cop out but it's always worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the counters worked for me.